# System message renders a "—"... very favorably ♪

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The community-generated election banner is supposed to have a dash (`—`) separating the start and the link. Instead, it renders something like the following. Note that even if you copy and paste it from the banner, you'll get the dash.

[image: I'm flattered, haha~. It's a music note. Not the note I use, but a note nonetheless.]

I wasn't sure if it was just me, but on chat Arda Xi [reported the same behavior](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/440810#440810), so I'm inclined to believe there is a global issue here.

Comment: If anyone else had been responsible for the system message, I'd take it as a bug at face value... but from Grace? I could've sworn the note was intentional.

Comment: status-bydesign ♬

Comment: Of course this is just an intentional hint to get you to nominate.

Comment: You do know that you can change that, right? :) but I like it the way it is!

Comment: @Oak Well, I could. In fact, when I originally saw the banner, I did a double take and assumed that one of you two *must* have made it. But then I saw what the actual text was.

Comment: The system message page lists the author of each message., so you can check there who is the offender.

Comment: @Oak Community generated.

Comment: If it was Status-bydesign why has it been changed!!?!?! WE WANT OUR NOTE BACK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the system, it's the font.

Volter Goldfish does not have a dash in the typical sense. It has a note. Likewise, it's also has [several other 'alternate' versions](http://www.dafont.com/volter-goldfish.font) of various characters. (Scroll down, I particularly like the cup of coffee)

It has a hyphen character though, which looks just like a normal hyphen, and seems to slot nicely into place:

[image: fixed]

Comment: System Message is the name of that banner, actually. I thought I had mentioned "font", but apparently that was only in the original draft of this bug report.

Comment: status-bydesign ♬ this is hilarious